# Неопределенный объект

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, typescript, angular

2 проекта, серверный и клиент, сервер ASP.NET Core, Клиент- Angular 8.
Опять Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Дела обстоят так, принимаю с сервера объект User, все идет нормально, создаю форму по объекту в хтмл, на деле все работает, все распознано и вставляется в свои места, но в консоли получаю Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.
Код сервера:

```
[HttpGet, Route("getuser")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
            return Ok(user);
        }
```

Код компонента:

```
export class EditUserComponent implements OnInit {  

  constructor(private router: Router, activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, public http: HttpClient,) {}
  user: User;
  invalidLogin: boolean;
  ngOnInit() {   
    let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/api/user/getuser",
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        })
      }).subscribe((response:User) => {
        this.user = response;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err)
      });     
  }
```

Код хтмл:

```
<form class="form-signin" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm)">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
    <div *ngIf="invalidLogin" class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username or password.</div>
    <br />

    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="user.id" id="id" name="id" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="id" required>
    <br />
    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Login</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.userName" id="username" name="username" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus>
    <br />
    <label for="lastname" class="sr-only">LastName</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" id="lastname" name="lastname" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="LastName" required>
    <br />
    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" id="password" name="password" ngModel class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Код самой сущьности в Ангуляре:

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public userName: string,
    public password: string,
    public lastName:string
  ) { }

}
```

Повторюсь-на деле все идеально, все работает как часы, если не открывать консоль, то ошибку и не заметить, но не могу понять почему она там...

С сервера приходит:
{"id":1,"userName":"laki_winners","password":"123","lastName":"lw1234"}

П.С. Знаю что id пока коряво запихал в форму, но это чисто для проверки, в дальнейшем скрою, да и если я убираю id, то ошибка ругается на userName, уберу userName, она ругается на lastName и так далее, в общем user будто неопределен, хотя по факту все работает и я получаю данные из юзера и она вставляются в форму как надо.

Comment: есть подозрение, что вы в своем компоненте сначала пытаетесь отобразить пустого юзера (при это пишется ошибка в консоль), потом загружаете юзера с сервера и отоображаете нормального юзера.

Comment: @tym32167 так и есть, вопрос как мне назначить юзера поумолчанию, вернее что ему присвоить до загрузки...

Comment: @tym32167 либо как то надо сделать, чтобы обозначить сначала, потом отобразить...

Comment: @tym32167 сделал так user: User = new User(0, " ", " ", " "); и все теперь отлично, сразу появляется нужный юзер и нет ошибок, единственно - корректно ли так делать?

Comment: там в ваших ангулярах есть вроде конструкция `ng-if` или типа того, то есть вы можете её использовать, чтобы не рендерить юзера, если его нет

Comment: @tym32167 идеально!!! Вновь благодарствую Артем:) <div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="user"> и все отлично!

Comment: на здоровье :) Можете оформить самоответ, мне нет смысла копипастить ваше решение в ответы.

Comment: @tym32167 так и сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Компонент вызывал сначала пустого юзера, а потом перезаписывал в него данные из сервера, проблему решило - `<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="user">`. Другими словами задал условие, если юзер не пустой, то все ок.